# How to update (more than one?) JPanel on mouse click?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouselistener

I have a `JFrame`, comprised of three `JPanel` containers, each panel has a filled-in circle (for example, red, white blue).

What I'd like to be able to do is update the color of the filled-in circle of that panel (make it darker with `Color.RED.darker`, for example) when that particular panel is clicked

I can't use an `ActionListener`, since panels aren't components but containers. I started out using `MouseListener`, but have now updated this to MouseAdapter. I am able to determine which `JPanel` was clicked - for testing purposes I'm printing out which panel was clicked to the console (for simplicity purposes I added a name to each panel).

EDIT: I got this mostly working - I can now repaint() the Jpanel that was clicked, making that cricle color darker, using the suggestion below of creating a setCircleColor (color) method, which calls repaint().This redraws the circle in that panel, using a darker color.

However, what I really also need to do is make the other two (non-clicked) cirlces on the other panels to repaint() with *lighter* colors.

But I can't see an easy way to handle this - how can I manipulate the other Jpanels that I *didn't* click on?

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;


public class TrafficLight {

    // sets up the frame, calls the circle panels and adds them to the frame
    public static void setUpGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Traffic Lights");
        frame.setSize(300, 900);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0));


        DrawCirclePanel redCircle = new DrawCirclePanel(Color.RED);
        DrawCirclePanel yellowCircle = new DrawCirclePanel(Color.YELLOW);
        DrawCirclePanel greenCircle = new DrawCirclePanel(Color.GREEN);

        redCircle.setName("redCircle");
        yellowCircle.setName("yellowCircle");
        greenCircle.setName("greenCircle");

        CircleListener cl = new CircleListener();

        redCircle.addMouseListener(cl);
        yellowCircle.addMouseListener(cl);
        greenCircle.addMouseListener(cl);

        frame.add(redCircle);
        frame.add(yellowCircle);
        frame.add(greenCircle);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setUpGui();
    }
}

// the DrawCirclePanel class creates a panel and
// draws a filled-in circle on the panel
class DrawCirclePanel extends JPanel {
    Color c;
    Border blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);

    // constructor for panel, takes Color as argument
    // so we know what color circle to make
    public DrawCirclePanel(Color color) {

        this.c = color;
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        this.setBorder(blackline);
    }

    // draws the circle in the panel
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int xWidth = this.getParent().getWidth();
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillOval(1, 1, xWidth-1, xWidth-1);
    }

    public void setCircleColor(Color color) {
        this.c = color;
        this.getGraphics().setColor(c);
        this.repaint();
    }
}


class CircleListener extends MouseAdapter {

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        DrawCirclePanel cPanel = (DrawCirclePanel) e.getSource();
        System.out.println(cPanel);
        String name = cPanel.getName();
        if (name == "redCircle") {
            cPanel.setCircleColor(Color.red.darker());
        }
        else if (name == "yellowCircle") {
            cPanel.setCircleColor(Color.yellow.darker());
        }
        else {
            cPanel.setCircleColor(Color.green.darker());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could create one `CircleListener` class that extends `MouseListener` and create one instance of the class, which you add to the three `JPanels`.

Comment: Thanks - actually realized that MouseAdapter probably better fits my needs, am trying that now.

Comment: *"I still can't quite figure out how to update the panel"* Why not? Note that [`MouseEvent.getComponent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/ComponentEvent.html#getComponent()) will provide a reference to it.

Comment: I know how to identify which component (which panel) was clicked - for example, I know if the panel with the red circle was clicked. What I can't figure out is how to have that red circle become a circle of a different color.

Comment: Have `DrawCirclePanel` implement a `setCircleColor(Color)` method that changes the color and calls `repaint()`. Hopefully, it's obvious that if the app. needs an 'incremental' color change (like making the color `darker()`), then it also needs a `getCircleColor()` method to be called in the `MouseListener`. Well, either those two methods or a single `makeCircleDarker()` method which takes no parameters and leaves the nuts & bolts to the custom painted panel itself. **BTW** `public void paint(Graphics g) { ..` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g); ..`

Answer (score 0):

So the answer turned out to be fairly simple.
Declare the panels with the circles as static variables so that the `MouseListener` class can access all three of the panels.

As Andrew Thompson noted, set up a `setCircleColor` method in `DrawCirclePanel` that repaints the circle with a different color as needed.

In the `MouseListener` class, determine with panel was called, then repaint all three of the circles, passing in the correct color - darker() or brighter() - as needed.

Here's the final code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;


public class TrafficLight {

    static DrawCirclePanel redCircle;
    static DrawCirclePanel yellowCircle;
    static DrawCirclePanel greenCircle;


    // sets up the frame, calls the circle panels and adds them to the frame
    public static void setUpGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Traffic Lights");
        frame.setSize(300, 900);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0));

        redCircle = new DrawCirclePanel(Color.RED.brighter().brighter());
        yellowCircle = new DrawCirclePanel(Color.YELLOW.darker().darker());
        greenCircle = new DrawCirclePanel(Color.GREEN.darker().darker());

        redCircle.setName("redCircle");
        yellowCircle.setName("yellowCircle");
        greenCircle.setName("greenCircle");

        CircleListener cl = new CircleListener();

        redCircle.addMouseListener(cl);
        yellowCircle.addMouseListener(cl);
        greenCircle.addMouseListener(cl);

        frame.add(redCircle);
        frame.add(yellowCircle);
        frame.add(greenCircle);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setUpGui();
    }
}


// the DrawCirclePanel class creates a panel and
// draws a filled-in circle on the panel
class DrawCirclePanel extends JPanel {
    Color c;
    Border blackLine = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);

    // constructor for panel, takes Color as argument
    // so we know what color circle to make
    public DrawCirclePanel(Color color) {
        this.c = color;
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        this.setBorder(blackLine);
    }

    // draws the circle in the panel
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int xWidth = this.getParent().getWidth();
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, xWidth, xWidth);
    }

    // changes the color and calls repaint after a mouseClicked event
    public void setCircleColor(Color color) {
        this.c = color;
        this.getGraphics().setColor(c);
        this.repaint();
    }
}

//abstract adapter class for receiving mouse events
class CircleListener extends MouseAdapter {

    // determine which panel was clicked; redraws as brighter circle
    // redraws other circles with dimmer (darker) color
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        DrawCirclePanel cPanel = (DrawCirclePanel) e.getSource();
        String name = cPanel.getName();
        if (name.equals("redCircle")) {
            TrafficLight.redCircle.setCircleColor(Color.RED.brighter().brighter());
            TrafficLight.yellowCircle.setCircleColor(Color.YELLOW.darker().darker());
            TrafficLight.greenCircle.setCircleColor(Color.GREEN.darker().darker());
        } else if (name.equals("yellowCircle")) {
            TrafficLight.redCircle.setCircleColor(Color.RED.darker().darker());
            TrafficLight.yellowCircle.setCircleColor(Color.YELLOW.brighter().brighter());
            TrafficLight.greenCircle.setCircleColor(Color.GREEN.darker().darker());
        } else {
            TrafficLight.redCircle.setCircleColor(Color.RED.darker().darker());
            TrafficLight.yellowCircle.setCircleColor(Color.YELLOW.darker().darker());
            TrafficLight.greenCircle.setCircleColor(Color.GREEN.brighter().brighter());
        }
    }
}
```